Should one not touch a fire with one's feet?
Many scholars tell us that one should not show one's feet to a fire. Is this true? Is there a relevant shastra pramana?

Yes. There are multiple texts which say that fire shouldn't be touched by feet. This is because fire (or more specifically sanctified fire) is considered to be the mouth of the Devas.

Plz give reference
